# How to generate a tensor of desired features, extracted from RGB images using pre-trained models?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to generate a 1D vector of features extracted from RGB images (256 x 256 x 3), using pre-trained models. Suppose I started from a tensor whose shape is (N_images, 256, 256, 3) I would like to obtain a tensor whose shape is (N_images, M_features), where M_features is the number of features, chose by the user.
I found a feasible solution in the keras/tensorflow [documentation](https://keras.io/api/applications/) (see: “Extract features with VGG16”) and I try the following code (using ResNet50):

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
N_images= img_data.shape[0]
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(256,256,3))
model.summary()
img_data = preprocess_input(img_data)
res_feature = model.predict(img_data)
res_feature.shape
```

However, the shape of the feature set is (N_images, 8 ,8 ,2048). Therefore, I added a GlobalAveragePooling2D layer:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from tensorflow.keras import Model, Input, regularizers
N_images= img_data.shape[0]
base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(256,256,3))**strong text**
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D() (x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=x)
img_data = preprocess_input(img_data)
res_feature = model.predict(img_data)
res_feature.shape
```

In this case, the shape of the output tensor is (N_images, 2048), that could be ok but I would like to chose a specific number of desired features.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pooling Layers are a generalization method, meaning you'll lose information. If all you're trying to do is hVe a specific shape, you can just use a dense layer with however many neurons you want.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want an autoencoder, which is basically trying to do dimensionality reduction of a convex latent space... it's simpler than what it seems (given a desired dimension `M`):

- create the "dataset":

```
res_feature = model.predict(img_data)
res_feature = np.reshape(res_feature, (len(res_feature), -1))
```

- create the autoencoder:

```
input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=res_feature.shape[1:])
encoder = tf.keras.layers.Dense(M, activation="selu")(input)
decoder = tf.keras.layers.Dense(shape=res_feature.shape[1:], activation="linear")

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input, outputs=decoder)
```

- compile and train it with your fav optimizer and the correct loss

Comment: Thanks Alberto, but I got several errors, related to the shape of output. Anyway, what I would like to do is to extract features using the convolutional part of pretrained models without training additional layers. Otherwise, I could implement ex novo an autoencoder and extract features from the bootleneck.

Comment: @Mattia_C how do you think you can find a latent space without training a model? is not that you can randomly pick some dimensions and some transformation and magically they appears. If you want to find a latent dimension, pick an algorithm like PCA, or an autoencoder and train it on the output of that layer